# How to pass data to edit modal from @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

```
<tbody>
            @foreach($courses as $course)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $course->course_code }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $course->course_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $course->description }}</td>
                    @if(is_null($course->teacher))
                        <td></td>
                    @else
                    <td>{{ $course->teacher->last_name }}, {{ $course->teacher->first_name }}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="assign-modal btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignModal" data-id="{{ $course->id }}">
                            <i class="bi bi-person-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

This is my table body

```
<!-- Assign Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="assignModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="assignModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="assignModalLabel">Assign Teacher</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @if(!empty($course->id))
                    <form method="POST" action={{ route('courses.update', $course->id) }}>
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="" id="course-id" hidden="">
                        <select class="form-control select-teacher" style="widht: 100%" name="teacher_id">
                            @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
                                <option value="{{ $teacher->id }}">{{ $teacher->last_name }}, {{ $teacher->first_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Assign</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is my Modal.

Apparently, it was working fine until yesterday, but It's no longer work.
The problem now with my code is that only the last column of data is editable. How can I modify the values ​​of other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each modal must have a specific id, try by adding {{ $course->id }} to tag id and aria-labelledby attribute

```
<div class="modal fade" id="assignModal{{ $course->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="assignModalLabel{{ $course->id }}" aria-hidden="true">
```

the previous code must also be inside a `foreach loop` as the first one in tbody

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <div class="modal fade" id="assignModal{{ $course->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="assignModalLabel{{ $course->id }}" aria-hidden="true">
        ...
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And also update all id in modal tag as previous
An id must be unique.

And also update as following to attach button to the specific id

```
<button type="button" class="assign-modal btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignModal{{ $course->id }}" data-id="{{ $course->id }}">
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question.
It still doesn't work. When I apply this solution, the modal of other rows does not open.

I think there is a problem with the bootstrap js file, but I don't know how to fix it.. it's imported as a web source.

Comment: Are you sure you updated button in the foreach.?
Which error do you have.?

Comment: Yes, I updated button in the foreach. Only the modal in the last row works, the rest don't appear.

Comment: I see you have not put the code inside a foreach, its why. You must also put the code of the modal inside `@foreach($courses as $course) ... @endforeach`, To duplicate the modal for each other, otherwise the value of $course would be the last row.

Comment: Oh, why didn't I think of that? That makes sense!  Thank you so much you save my day.